# Books for (Complex) Algebraic Curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, textbook-recommendation

I would like suggestions for some good books on (Complex) Algebraic Curves.

I am searching a book for Undergraduate-Beginner Level in this part of mathematics: algebraic curves. I found some books like "Plane Algebraic Curves" from Gerd Fischer, "Complex Algebraic Curves" from Frances Kirwan, "Elementary Geometry of Algebraic Curves: An Undergraduate Introduction" from Gibson but these were too difficult for my level.

Also, please suggest my a book (or combine chapters of books or notes), which covers the following topics:

1. **Plane Curves;** The set of points $V(f)$ of a plane curve, Transformations in $\mathbb{C}^2$, Conics, Intersection number, Isolated (abnormal) points, tangent lines, rational curves
2. **Intersection Of Curves;** The projective space, Lines in projective space, Projective transformations, Εquivalence of projective curves, Intersection number, Irregular poits, Tangent Lines, Flex points, Rational Projective Curves
3. **Linear Systems of Curves;** Intersection Points, Bézout's theorem

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: William Fulton has a book on this topic. http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

Comment: I really enjoyed reading [Plane algebraic curves](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-0493-6) by Brieskorn/Knörrer.

Comment: @Xiqiang QIN I found Fulton too difficult for undergraduate. Could you suggest me something else? Thank you.

Comment: @Takumi Murakami I will check it! Thank you!

Comment: If my memory serves me right, Gibson's book talks exactly about that.

Comment: Gibson's book is very elementary; he assumes only linear algebra and several variable calculus. If you don't have that background, you would be better off to learn some linear algebra and some several variable calculus first before trying to learn about algebraic curves.

Comment: You could try my lectures notes for Concrete Algebra: http://euclid.ucc.ie/Mckay/

Comment: @FanZheng Yes, your memory is right. Gibson's is very near for my purpose.

Comment: @BenMcKay I agree with you, and I feel I have the background. But, I would like to avoid field extensions for algebraic curves. And this was the reason I wrote "complex" algebraic curves. Furthermore, I found your notes very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: H. Clemens: A scrapbook of complex curve theory.

Answer (score 8):

A good classical book is Walker, Algebraic curves, Princeton, 1950.
A  more modern one on the same elementary level is 
Gerd Fischer, Plane algebraic curves, AMS, 2001.

Both books a small and elementary, ideal for the first introduction.

Comment: Does Walker use field extensions? Thank you.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, he does, but not much. Beginning from Chap V, section 2.

Comment: Do you have something on your mind without extensions? Walker looks great, but I can't use extensions yet.

Comment: @Chris: Your strange requirement essentially puts us back to 19th century. Try Salmon,  
A treatise on the higher plane curves, but this can be really hard reading, unlike modern books that I recommended.

Comment: You are right. I had a look in these books and I will prefer the mordern books which do not use too much extensions. I think the best for my case is Gibson's. Something else in Gibson's spirit? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 7):

When I was a student I liked a lot the book by Egbert Brieskorn and Horst Knörrer: *Plane Algebraic Curves*. I can recommend it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I saw this book, it was well written and clear.

Answer (score 6):

Rick Miranda's [*Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-5/) is a great place to look for a more complex analytic point of view. I think it starts from very little and only asks you know a bit of complex analysis. See [here](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~pablos/files/AlgCurv-RS-Miranda.pdf) for a review of this book by Gunning.

As David Lehavi has already recommended in the comments, Herbert Clemens's [*A Scrapbook of Complex Curve Theory*](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-55/) is a beautiful panorama into all the topics you mention. The treatment of technical material is perhaps a bit brief, but it provides marvelous intuition as well as a coherent picture as to how everything fits together.

Finally, Miles Reid's [*Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/undergraduate-algebraic-geometry/84874864072D5C134D2C4A3C4A186922), again although somewhat informal, is simply a fascinating read, if nothing other than for the Woffle that begins the book. See [here](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/MA4A5/UAG.pdf) for a pretty $\TeX$ version by Reid himself.

Answer (score 4):

Keith Kendig's [A guide to plane algebraic curves](https://www.maa.org/press/books/a-guide-to-plane-algebraic-curves) is quite elementary and readable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ll have a look!

Answer (score 3):

Another beginner-friendly book is [P.A. Griffiths, Introduction to algebraic curves](https://books.google.com/books?id=n_gGel1N1cAC).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This book is really useful!